# Unexpected token. A constructor, method,accessor or property expected

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I was following a tutorial and wanted to get data across pages, but I dont understand why it is showing this error.
my code:

about.ts(page1, sending data from here)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'page-about',
templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

param1:string; param2:string;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
param1 = ""; param2 = "";
}


this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage, {
param1: 'John', param2: 'Johnson'
});

}
```

home.ts(page1, sending data on this page)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {

}

this.parameter1 = navParams.get('param1'); 
this.parameter2 = navParams.get('param2');
alert(this.parameter1);

}
```

heres the error screenshot
[image]

screenshot continued
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you define a class properties. This is more like it. Not sure if that will solve your problem, but it does seem a lot neater:

```
export class HomePage {

    public parameter1: string;
    public parameter2: string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {
       this.parameter1 = this.navParams.get('param1'); 
       this.parameter2 = this.navParams.get('param2');
       alert(this.parameter1);
    }     
}
```

Same deal concerning your `AboutPage` component. Perhaps it's a good idea to first look at the [angular.io](https://angular.io) page and see how they construct components/classes. And while you are at it, taking a look at basic OO `TypeScript` will also help you

**update**

One of the errors comes from your `AboutPage` component, besides the issue with the wrong class definition, you also talk about a `SecondPage` even though it's not imported.

The other error is like I said, coming from your `HomePage` component.

Comment: It is giving me the same error again, yeah i will have to brush up my concepts first.Thanks for the link